# Site Header Image not showing on two specific pages within site

Tags: css

The problem, Ill try and be brief and specific, Is the site logo located in 
        header class="site-header"
 does not appear at the top of my site like it should on these pages :- http://webdesignbird.co.uk/portfolio/ and http://webdesignbird.co.uk/blog/.

The site header should be displayed on the left with my logo inside, as it appears on my site homepage (look at this for reference). In firebug, the css for this header and site-title (just on my two problem pages) appears in light grey, as if firebug is pointing out that the css is there, just not visible on the page. the logo and the site-header used to appear fine on these pages, but I have somehow lost it.

I would leave code snippets here for your reference but I am not sure what part of the code is causing the issue. I have been stuck on this for a while now, I asked the question earlier and it was closed. Not sure why. I apologise in advance if stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post question again but I am aiming to stay within your rules and advice.

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Thankyou for the advice. I realise now if its a specific problem to me I shouldn't post here, If it is code to help people on other sites I should post here. I will delete the question and go elsewhere. thanks

Comment: I have 'undeleted' as someone has posted the answer for me. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
.site-header #site_title, .site-header #site_tagline {
    display: none;
}
```

to

```
.site-header #site_title, .site-header #site_tagline {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: thanks worked! I now realise those pages show the 'site-title' and the other pages show the logo header image. Altough the page doesn't show my logo, I am happy with it just showing the site title. Thanks again for your help

Comment: The css was located in my skin css files so I just added your fix to my main custom css file with an (! important) tag.

Comment: you can always load your custom.css AFTER the skin.css file. Always try to avoid !important whenever possible

Comment: The above fix actually created errors in other pages, so I fixed by targeting the two specific pages with problems i.e. body.template-home .site-header #site_title, body.template-portfolio .site-header #site_title (display: block;). Also I cannot load custom.css after skin.css on thesis I don't think. It creates one css.css out of the two stylesheets. I may be wrong but that's what I found in the past. I did't actually need !important in the end too, was just making sure. Thanks for all your help, much appreciated